# Twitter Bootstrap's ".input-prepend" with a Django Form

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Django and have been using [django-bootstrap-form](https://github.com/tzangms/django-bootstrap-form). I've been pretty happy with it, but I don't believe it provides a way to format the output for ".input-prepend" as described in [Twitter Bootstrap's docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#prependedInput).

I'm guessing I'm going to have to override my input field's widget for this particular field. I'm not sure of the best way to do this, though. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to edit the templates, adding an if clause for prepending and possibly two more for appending or both cases at once or handle this with a templatetag (or beter even, the widget [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.render) method).

Have a look what's [there](https://github.com/tzangms/django-bootstrap-form/blob/master/bootstrapform/templatetags/bootstrap.py) to get the hang of it.

For the field itself either create a custom [formfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields) or create a widget by [wrapping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#multiwidget) a basic widget.